# Concurrency in Spike/Newlib

Tags: concurrency, pthreads, riscv, newlib, spike

How do I simulate concurrent programs in the Spike RISC-V ISS using newlib?

What I know is that Spike has a -p flag to simulate multiple processors, but I can't use pthreads or other such system calls since they are not part of newlib. Do I need to install the linux compiler toolchain and simulate a whole linux system for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just run FreeRTOS, either the contributed RISC-V Spike Simulator GCC [port](https://interactive.freertos.org/hc/en-us/community/posts/210030246-32-bit-and-64-bit-RISC-V-using-GCC), or the official one in the case it would support spike - I am not sure it does, but it does support qemu if you don't mind using qemu instead of spike.

Comment: @Yano KX: If this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is of course no obligation to do this.